# Adding a shadow at the edge of the UIView(Picture inside)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios7, core-graphics

So, I am looking for the most practical way to adding a shadow at the edge of UIView like shown in the picture below. I tried some ways that I read but really couldn't make them work as I wanted. It would be nice if someone had an idea how apple does this in their apps.

Picture link(Didn't want to post it directly here as it was pretty big): [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NEtY.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following properties deal with shadows on UIViews:

```
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 25;
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-3, 0);
```

That code will make a black shadow at half opacity, with a shadow radius of 25 pixels, and shifted 3 pixels to the left. You'll need to add the following import to the top of the file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

You may also need to add the QuartzCore framework to your project if it isn't already.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void) configureSlideLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-3, 0);
    layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    layer.shadowPath =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
}
...
[self configureSlideLayer:self.view.layer];
```

source: https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu